# Quests that won't clear

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I acually have two questions.
How do I complete a quest if when I go to the place where the arrow is pointing, the quest turns out to be void?
Like for instance; Esborn wanted me to brin him a Dragon scale and a dragon bone.
When I brought these things to him, nothing else happened.
the same words from our previous conversation would only show and not the one concerning the dragon scale & bone.
Another quest wanted me to "receive a reading from Olava the feeble".
When I go to her house ( where the arrow is pointing ) she demands that I leave her house.
When I see her outside and press "A" to talk to her, she says nothing.
This is the same with outer quests tha I have.
Skyrim is an awesome game, but it's pretty F$#@ up!

Answer (score 2):

Sadly skyrim is a very glitchy game, in fact i have met 3 glitches that have caused me to restart the game.Now,when you start to clear holds as the storm cloaks or imperials the game will have more bugs since the leaders of the holds are switched pending on which faction you clear it with.Those quests that you can not complete or the quests that say you still have a step to do(even though you completed all the steps) will never go away.I am afraid you will just have to deal with it.    For an example of how glitchy skyrim is click this link!

I hope this post has cleared a little bit for you